# overriding hashchange event, is it possible?

Tags: javascript

I have a web app with 3 sections. Whenever the user completes one section the next one will slide (not simply appear) into view. I'm doing this with backbone.js' routing, so hash fragments. What I want is to enable history so if the user presses the back button it will slide back to the previous section. I tried overriding the hashchange event in the jQuery [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/), but that didn't work. Any ideas?

```
$(window).hashchange(function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();             
    router.navigate(window.location.hash); // The router invokes the function that slides the appropriate section into view
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault` won't work since the hash chance is a contrived, not actual DOM event.

Comment: Are all section's hash the same?? Does the hash change when going forward to the next section? Why do you need to override the change?

Comment: It goes from #page1 to #page2 and finally #page3.